# Copy one plist into another

Tags: xcode, plist

I would like to copy the info from my plist in one project and then include it in another plist in a different project. But I does't seem to be possible to copy more then one item at time. Is it possible to make this so you don't have to move every post yourself? (just to mention, both my plists have the same name but in different projects)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Right click the plist in the navigator and select show as --> source code, copy/paste to 2nd project. Or just drag the .plist file into navigator of your new app.